# Search/replace regex and text

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to use search/replace in Notepad++ organize a set of data copied from the web. How can I remove spaces from the data so that my data is on one line?

My goal is to convert multiple lines of data into 1 row, separated by semicolons

[image: Data before formatting]

**Data after formatting (goal):**

```
Action-Report

Active Hospice Members; List of active members in Hospice.; Community & Other CarePlus: Care Mgmt; 7/20/2018 9:34 PM Jenkins, Pathway
```

Comment: Add text to the post. Do not add images of text.

Comment: Have you tried something? What doesn't work?

Answer (score -2):

[Simple when you know how](https://regex101.com/r/Mt1QG8/1)

`\s*\n`